# mpi4py behaving strangely

Tags: python, mpi, pickle

Trying to load a pickle in a number of processes with mpi4py.  Here's what I had which was working well most of the time:

```
for ix in range(len(frames)):
    if comm.rank == 0:
        frame = frames[ix]
        logging.debug("{0}: doing stuff, frame {1}".format(comm.rank,frame))
        W, nodes = pickle.load(open(os.path.join(args.network_dir, '{0}.pkl'.format(frame))))
        freqs = np.random.normal(0., 5.*np.pi/180., size = len(W))
    else:
        W = None
        nodes = None
        freqs = None

    comm.Barrier()

    W = comm.bcast(W, root = 0)
    nodes = comm.bcast(nodes, root = 0)
    freqs = comm.bcast(freqs, root = 0)

    comm.Barrier()
```

But it gets reliably stuck on the broadcast step.  freqs needs to be the same for all processes, so it must be generated by one process.  I could have everybody load the pickle themselves like:

```
for ix in range(len(frames)):
    frame = frames[ix]
    logging.debug("{0}: doing stuff, frame {1}".format(comm.rank,frame))
    W, nodes = pickle.load(open(os.path.join(args.network_dir, '{0}.pkl'.format(frame))))

    if comm.rank == 0:
        freqs = np.random.normal(0., 5.*np.pi/180., size = len(W))
    else:
        freqs = None

    # broadcast and stuff
```

But then everybody loads a different pickle! That's not supposed to happen, right?  Every process should enter the loop at ix = 0, correct?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a python expert, but a couple of general comments. First, you need to make sure that every process calls the broadcast the same number of times: is the "for" loop guaranteed to have the same number of iterations on every process? Second, you do not need the Barrier either before or after the broadcast: the broadcast (like all collectives)  ensures that any required synchronisation is done for you automatically.

Comment: Yes. The for loop should be guaranteed to have the same iterations for every process, which is why it's really confusing that everyone comes in on a different frame for the second option.  I'll put simply one Barrier after the broadcast and see if that helps.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a clearer description of the observed behavior. An obvious error would be if `frames` is not equal on each rank.